# $ gulp ... ERROR finding 'bower_components/polymer/polymer.html' - Polymer Starter Kit (v.1)

Tags: build, gulp, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

## Polymer Starter Kit (ERROR: build 'dist' folder)

Here's a link to the source code where the problem exists: 
https://github.com/oneezy/wwwSFI

I did quite a bit of re-organizing the PSK (version 1) after seeing how the [Shop App: (Case Study)](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/case-study) was put together. In this process, I managed to mess up my process for building out the 'dist' folder. Everything runs through fine up until vulcanize:

```
$ gulp
[13:09:11] Starting 'vulcanize'...

ERROR finding ../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html
ERROR finding ../bower_components/iron-icons/hardware-icons.html
```

[(Open Image)](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/7369575/15755287/a9b92276-28c1-11e6-843f-8de0dffcf902.png)
[image]

---

Next, I try to serve up the dist folder, and receive the error:

`$ gulp serve:dist`

[(Open Image)](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/7369575/15755358/00d574e2-28c2-11e6-87da-77c417ca36cd.png)
[image]

---

When serving up in developer mode, it works just fine:

`$ gulp serve`

[(Open Image)](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/7369575/15755432/64657b2e-28c2-11e6-9c08-1eae54691306.png)
[image]

---

Here's a shot of my `folder structure`, `index.html` file, and `elements.html` file:

[(Open Image)](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/7369575/15755490/a6b0b08e-28c2-11e6-8092-c7d63b4faf47.png)
[image]

---

Any ideas?

Comment: Answered in https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-starter-kit/issues/843#issuecomment-223700136